# Hubot only showing images for one user

Tags: xmpp, openfire, hubot, adium

I have setup Hubot for our company. It's working correctly, connecting to group chats, responding to its name, etc. The only issue is it won't show images, it just shows the link (which goes to the proper image).

```
Protocol: XMPP  
Encryption: SSL/TSL  
Client program: Adium (1.5.9 w/ adinline plugin for images)  
Server program: Openfire (Not sure of the version)
```

I am the one who set hubot up and Adium is showing images properly for me, but not for anyone else. Has anyone ran into this issue? or have any idea of where I should look to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out with the help of a coworker. In my company we all login to the same server and everyone is visible to everyone else. It turns out that the adinline plugin requires the bot to be on your buddy list before images will show.

http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=7926

This really comes down to me not reading the instructions :( Anyway the issue is resolved. woot!